# java.lang.String org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams.toQueryString()

Tags: java, scala, solr, solrj

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams.toQueryString()'
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.createMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:398)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:234)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:131)
    at in.co.adgebra.solr.KafkaStream$.delayedEndpoint$in$co$adgebra$solr$KafkaStream$1(KafkaStream.scala:59)
```

here is my code in scala

```scala
val solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build()
solrClient.add("test_core", doc)
solrClient.commit()`
```

can you tell me whats the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a "classic issue" if you have several different versions of a dependency/JAR expected/pulled by different pieces of code.

Typical scenario:

- dependency A is compiled against Solr version N and expect to have version N of Solr JARs in classpath at runtime.
- dependency B is pulling a Solr JAR version M

To troubleshoot these kind of issues, you usually ask your build tool to list the dependency tree and figure out what conflict exist.